# Using ArcPy UpdateCursor to Update a field

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor

In my data I have one field (`L1_SOILTYP`) and a new field I created (`SoilClass`). I am trying to use update cursor to assign classification values (1-17) based on the values found in the `L1_SOILTYP` field. For example... `'Clay'` and `'CLAY'` should be assigned '1'. I am using ArcGIS Pro for this.

Following an example on this page... https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm ... this is the code I have come up with...

```
import arcpy
fc = 'D:\GIS\PollinatorProject\Pollinator\Pollinator.gdb\soil_samples'
fields = ['L1_SOILTYP', 'SoilClass2']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if(row[0] == 'CLAY,DUMP'or row[0] == 'CLAY(WEATHERED SHALE)'or row[0] == 'FILL,CLAY'):
            row[1]= '1'
        elif(row[0] == 'SAND' or 'TOO SANDY' or row[0] == 'Sand, coarse' or row[0] == 'COARSE SAND'):
             row[1]= '2'
        elif(row[0] =='Sandy Clay' or row[0] == 'SAND & CLAY' or row[0] == 'SAND SOME CLAY'):
            row[1] = '3'
      
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Using this code the clay values are all correctly assigned the 1 value, but all the other soil types are assigned to 2. This is a shortened version of what I have, but each time I run the code, all values are assigned '1'

Comment: I'd use a dictionary for this pattern. Load all the valid values in a single dictionary to start, and assign `row[1] = options[row[0]] if row[0] in options else None`.  Then you can debug  your assignment issues.

Comment: What I mean to say is that all the clay values are assigned to 1 and all other values are assigned to 2 ie. sand, loam, concrete when I would like them to have unique values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to shorten your code:

```
import arcpy
fc = r'D:\GIS\PollinatorProject\Pollinator\Pollinator.gdb\soil_samples'
fields = ['L1_SOILTYP', 'SoilClass2']

type_to_class = {'CLAY,DUMP':'1', 'CLAY(WEATHERED SHALE)':'1', 'FILL,CLAY':'1',
                 'SAND':'2', 'TOO SANDY':'2', 'Sand, coarse':'2', 'COARSE SAND':'2',
                 'Sandy Clay':'3', 'SAND & CLAY':'3', 'SAND SOME CLAY':'3'} #Add all to dictionary

missing_types = []

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in type_to_class: #If you can have leading/trailing whitespaces, use if row[0].strip()
            row[1] = type_to_class[row[0]] #And here
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            missing_types.append(row[0])

    if len(missing_types)>0:
        print('Cant find soil types: {0}'.format(set(missing_types)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using BERA's suggestion this is the dictionary that was successful in creating the soil class values.

````
fc= r'D:\GIS\PollinatorProject\Pollinator\Pollinator.gdb\soil_samples'
fields = ['L1_SOILTYP', 'ClassofSoil']

type_to_class = {
    'CLAY, DUMP': '1',
    'DRY CLAY': '1',
    'Clay' : '1',
    'CLAY' : '1',
    'CLAY MOIST' : '1',
    'CLAY(WEATHERED SHALE)' : '1',
    'FILL, CLAY' : '1',
    'SAND' : '2',
    'TOO SANDY' : '2',
    'Sand, coarse' : '2',
    'COARSE SAND' : '2',
    'Sand' : '2',
    'CLEAN SAND' : '2',
    'VERY SANDY' : '2',
    'SANDY' : '2',
    'FINE SAND' : '2',
    'Fine Sand' : '2',
    'COURSE SAND' : '2',
    'Coures Sand' : '2',
    'Sandy Clay' :'3',
    'SAND & CLAY' :'3',
    'SAND SOME CLAY' :'3',
    'Clayey Sand' :'3',
    'CLAY SOME SAND' :'3',
    'CLAY,SOME SAND' :'3',
    'Sandy Caly' :'3',
    'SANDY CLAY' :'3',
    'COURSE SAND SOME CLAY' :'3',
    'SILT' : '4',
    'Silit' : '4',
    'SILTY' : '4',
    'Silty' : '4',
    'Silt' : '4',
    'MEDIUM' : '5',
    'FIRM' : '5',
    'NO DUMP' : '5',
    'SLAB/PLASTIC' : '5',
    'DUMP' : '5',
    'Dump' : '5',
    'TRACES OF DUMP' : '5',
    'SLAB' : '5', 
    'SOME DUMP' : '5',
    'SOME WOOD' : '5',
    'REJECTION' : '5',
    'TO 6(2)' : '5',
    'VERY SOFT' : '5',
    'WOOD' : '5',
    '2)' : '5',
    'VERY DAMP' : '5',
    'FILL' : '5',
    'SLAG': '5',
    'ASPHALT/FILL' : '6',
    'ASPHALT' : '6',
    'asphalt is newer' : '6',
    'asphalt is new' : '6',
    'Gravel & Sand' : '7',
    'SAND & GRAVEL (STRUCTURAL FILL' : '7',
    'SILTY GRAVEL & SAND' : '7',
    'GRAVLE & SAND' : '7',
    'Sand w/ Gravel' : '7',
    'COURSE SAND & GRAVEL' : '7',
    'Sand w/ gravel' : '7',
    'SAND & GRAVEL' : '7',
    'GRAVEL & SAND' : '7',
    'CLAYEY SAND & GRAVEL' : '7', 
    'Sand & Gravel' : '7',
    'SAND & gRAVEL' : '7',
    'Sand & Pea Gravel': '7', 
    'SAND & GRAVEL SOME CLAY' : '7',
    'Gravel Ballast' : '8',
    'LARGE GRAVEL' : '8',
    'GRAVEL' : '8',
    'SiltyClay' : '9',
    'Clayey Silt' :'9',
    'SILTY CALY' : '9',
    'SILTY CLAY' : '9',
    'CLAYEY SILT' : '9',
    'GRASS/TOPSOIL' :'10',
    'TOP SOIL' :'10',
    'CLAY & GRAVEL' :'11',
    'Sandy Clay & Gravel' :'11',
    'DUMP, BRICK' : '12',
    'CONCRETE' : '12',
    'RED BRICK' : '12',
    'BRICK' : '12',
    'SAND SOME BRICK' : '12',
    'Silty Sand' : '13',
    'Sandy Silt' : '13',
    'SAND & SILT' : '13',
    'SANDY SILT'  : '13',
    'SILTY SAND' : '13',
    'FINE SAND SILTY' : '13',
    'BASALT & SHALE' : '14',
    'SHALE' : '14',
    'BROWN SHALE' : '14',
    'CLAY, CINDERS' : '15', 
    'CINDERS & SILT' : '15', 
    'CINDERS' : '15', 
    'SANDSTONE' : '16', 
    'CLAYEY SANDSTONE' : '16', 
    'ROCK' : '17', 
    'LOAM' : '18', 
    'n/a' : '<NULL>',
    ' ' : '<NULL>'
}

missing_types = []

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row [0] in type_to_class:
            row[1] = type_to_class[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else: 
            missing_types.append(row[0])
    if len(missing_types)>0:
        print('Cant find soil types: {0}'.format(set(missing_types)))
    ```
````